# Interrupting Byte-Extraction from file

Tags: python, file, binary

I have a binary file with 11*32 Bytes (in this case, it should be dynamic), which represents a separated header for every 32 Byte-chunk. The introduction for the first header is set by the magic byte '5A'; the following header are numeric labeled like 0x01, 0x02, ..., 0xnn.

From following code, I'm extracting the 32 byte chunks and parsing the single bytes (little endian):

```
from struct import unpack

offsets = [1,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,1,1]
i = 0
zum={}
with open('file.bin', 'rb') as file:
    data_offset = unpack("<I",file.read(16)[12:16])[0]
    anz_pmcblock = int(data_offset/32)
    file.seek(0)
    for n in range(0,anz_pmcblock):
        pmcblock = file.readline(32)
        j=0
        for off in offsets:
            if j==0:
                zum[i]=[pmcblock[j:j+off]]
                j+=off
            else:
                zum[i].append(pmcblock[j:j+off])
                j+=off
        i+=1
```

The 10th Header (labeled as '0A') will be read as '\n' and is cancelling the further reading by readline(). If I'm changing this value the reading will be processed.

How can I open a file and read it as 'true binary', without encoding?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'true binary'.  I thought ```open('file.bin', 'rb')``` already opens it as a binary.  It's how you interpret the bits is what makes the encoding.

Comment: Why `readline`? Just use `read` if you want bytes of exact length. It is not made for raw data but for text.

Comment: @ivvija Ok, thanks for the fast reply... this solved it. i dont know why the chunk reading stucked with me for readline() and not read()...